# bootstrap dismiss modal and display another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having a bit of a problem with using Bootstraps modal,

I have a login form which uses a modal (when pressed the login form will appear)

If the user does not have an account, they can press "sign up" I would like the login modal to be dismissed and the sign up modal to appear

I have this working, the login form is dismissed when sign up is clicked, but when the sign up modal is shown, you cannot scroll up or down on the sign up modal, (you can scroll up or down on the login modal)

sorry for the long explanation, the jsfiddle below is my code,

```
<p> Don't have an account? <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"> Sign up</a>
```

This is the code which dismisses the login modal and shows the sign up modal. 
I know that the modal is dismissed via data-dismiss="modal" (so the page thinks the modal is closed and scrolls through the web page) however I do not know how to find a way around this.

http://jsfiddle.net/5v4nejsz/

The lorem ipsum is there to show the example of the scrolling.

The first form is the login modal and the second form is the sign up

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded with the following. I created a class with attribute overflow: hidden. Anytime the myModal1 opens, it's added to the body.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal("hide");   
    $('#myModal1').modal("toggle");
    $("body").addClass("notScroll");

});
```

When myModal1 closes, the class is removed:

```
$('#myModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("body").removeClass("notScroll");
});
```

Now, you have to allow myModal1 to scroll:

```
<modal... id="myModal1" style="overflow-y: scroll">
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5v4nejsz/22/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the fiddle

```
<p> Already't have an account? 
  <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Sign in </a>
</p>
```

So what I did here was first dismiss the first modal by order of operation. After that the next action is the display your login window again.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/floor_/5v4nejsz/18/)

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting, however, this was not the issue I was having. The issue is when you click on "sign up" in the login modal, you cannot scroll the sign up modal.

So, the login form works (and scrolls fine) 
The sign up form (once clicking on "dont have an account? Sign Up) does not scroll the modal up or down, but scrolls the webpage behind the modal. 

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. When I click on your fiddle click login button, Nothing scrolls. I click the sign up button and nothing scrolls in the modal but the back content page scrolls. Which do you want? The login page to scroll like that or do you want the sign up modal not to scroll the back content?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. 
When I click the login button, the login modal scrolls up and down (not the background).
When I click sign up, the sign up modal does not scroll, but the background scrolls. 
The login modal (when the login form scrolls) is correct. 
I would like the sign up modal to scroll up and down and for the background to not scroll. 

Thank you

Comment: well the login form doesn't scroll at all for me using your fiddle. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using firefox, still no scroll in chrome. Can you check the fiddle to make sure that is correct.

Comment: I have tried chrome, safari and firefox, the login modal is scrolling for all 3.